# Jenkins location in docker, not at /var/jenkins_home

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm installing Jenkins via docker by following this [official guide](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#debian-ubuntu).

After running command:

```
docker run \
  -u root \
  --rm \
  -d \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 50000:50000 \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

I'm expecting Jenkins to be installed @ `/var/jenkins_home`, but instead it is being installed @ `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins-data`.

Also there is no such folder as `/var/jenkins_home`.

Am I missing something. Please suggest.

*Thank You*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/var/jenkins_home` is inside the container. You are using named volume & that's why it's located in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins-data`.

Instead, you can use host bind mounts as below to ensure you get the data in `/var/jenkins_home` on the host machine -

```
docker run \
  -u root \
  --rm \
  -d \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 50000:50000 \
  -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Volumes path in case of host mounts has to be absolute else it results in creating a named volume.